# Should I create a separate DTO class for each Service method?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, architecture, soa

There is a Service to work with a `Customer` entity.

Service already implements a `GetCustomer` method which returns a `CustomerDTO`.

Service must implement methods to change Customer's `Phone`, `Address`, `SalesManager` and `Discount`. Customer is allowed to change only `Phone` and `Address`, Sales Director is allowed to change only Customer's `SalesManager`, while Sales Manager is allowed to change only Customer's `Discount`.

1. Should I create only one service method `ChangeCustomer`?

   - Should I use `CustomerDTO` which I used as a return type in `GetCustomer` method, e.g. `ChangeCustomer(CustomerDTO)`?
   - Should I use some other `CustomerChangeDTO`, e.g. `ChangeCustomer(CustomerChangeDTO)`?
2. Should I create several service methods `ChangeCustomerPhone`, `ChangeCustomerAddress`, `ChangeCustomerManager` and `ChangeCustomerDiscount`?

   - Should I use `CustomerDTO` in each of these service methods, e.g. `ChangeCustomerName(CustomerDTO)`, ...?
   - Should I user a separate DTO class in each of there service methods, e.g. `ChangeCustomerName(CustomerNameChangeDTO)`, ...?
3. Maybe some other set of service methods?

It seems that a single DTO class makes service much easier to use on client, because all client has to do is to request `CustomerDTO`, change some of it's properties and send back. Service is to process all changes in `CustomerDTO` and apply business logic to real `Customer` entity and maybe other entities.

Are there any other pros / cons for each variant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WCF service is in the application layer, so it should have a separate method for every use case. You clearly have 3 use cases here:

1. Customer can change `Phone` and `Address`
2. Sales Director can change `SalesManager`
3. Sales Manager can change `Discount`

So your service should expose 3 methods. Each of these methods will not only have to update `Customer` entity, it will have to check permissions first. If you try to implement it in 1 method, you will end up with a lot of `if`s and unclear behavior. For example what to do if a Sales Manager tries to change `Discount` and `Phone`? Ignore the `Phone`? Throw an exception?

Each method should use a different DTO, containing only properties necessary for the method. (Btw, you can change 'DTO' to 'Command' in the class names - for example `ChangeCustomerDiscountCommand`. Looks nicer than 'DTO').

If you use a single DTO, it will be confusing for the client (Why are there other properties in the class? What will happen if I leave them empty? What will happen if I change them? etc.)

Comment: hi Jakub, would he need a full Customer class in the domain layer with all the properties? Where first you load the Customer domain class from the resource access (CustomerRA->Customer), then apply necessary changes after checking security, then turn that full Customer class into CustomerRA to pass down to Resource for saving?